# LEFT OUTER JOIN generate incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have a problem with this query:

```
SELECT     RTRIM(LTRIM(L_MAILITMS.MAILITM_FID)) AS Ref30
         , IsNull (Ref33,0) as Ref33
FROM       L_MAILITM_EVENTS 
   INNER JOIN L_MAILITMS ON L_MAILITM_EVENTS.MAILITM_PID = L_MAILITMS.MAILITM_PID 
WHERE  (L_MAILITMS.MAIL_CLASS_CD = 'E') 
   AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS.EVENT_OFFICE_CD = 1063) 
   AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE_CD = 30) 
   AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS.EVENT_GMT_DT >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-27 00:00:00', 102)) 
   AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS.EVENT_GMT_DT < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-28 00:00:00', 102))
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT   RTRIM(LTRIM(L_MAILITMS_1.MAILITM_FID)) as Ref3033
           , COUNT(*) as Ref33
    FROM     L_MAILITM_EVENTS as L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1 
       INNER JOIN  L_MAILITMS as L_MAILITMS_1 ON L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1.MAILITM_PID = L_MAILITMS_1.MAILITM_PID
    WHERE  (L_MAILITMS_1.MAIL_CLASS_CD = 'E') 
       AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1.EVENT_OFFICE_CD = 1063) 
       AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1.EVENT_TYPE_CD = 33) 
       AND (L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1.EVENT_GMT_DT >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-27 00:00:00', 102))
    GROUP BY L_MAILITMS_1.MAILITM_FID
  )  ON L_MAILITMS.MAILITM_FID = L_MAILITMS_1.MAILITM_FID
```

an error is generated

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Table L_MAILITMS_EVENTS:

```
MAILITM_PID     EVENT_OFFICE_CD    EVENT_TYPE_CD
-----------------------------------------------------------
1               1063               30
2               1063               30
2               1063               33
3               1063               33
3               1063               30
4               1063               30
```

Table L_MAILITMS:

```
MAILITM_PID          MAILITM_FID        MAIL_CLASS_CD
-------------------------------------------------------
1                     123               E  
2                     452               E                
3                     369               E
4                     633               E
```

What i want to get:

```
Ref30          Ref33
-----------------------
123            0
452            1
369            1
633            0
```

**UPDATE :** Thanks Sebas for your help

*is there another way for this query to assure speed performance, because i treat about 2500 MAILITM_FID ?*

Can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: `JOINs` are a subclause of `FROM`, they can not appear after a `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then let me modify the placement of the joins:

```
    SELECT     RTRIM(LTRIM(m.MAILITM_FID)) AS Ref30
         , IsNull (Ref33,0) as Ref33
FROM       L_MAILITM_EVENTS me
   INNER JOIN L_MAILITMS m ON me.MAILITM_PID = m.MAILITM_PID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT   RTRIM(LTRIM(m1.MAILITM_FID)) as Ref3033
                   , COUNT(*) as Ref33
            FROM     L_MAILITM_EVENTS me1
                        INNER JOIN L_MAILITMS m1 ON me1.MAILITM_PID = m1.MAILITM_PID
            WHERE  (m1.MAIL_CLASS_CD = 'E') 
               AND (me1.EVENT_OFFICE_CD = 1063) 
               AND (me1.EVENT_TYPE_CD = 33) 
               AND (me1.EVENT_GMT_DT >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-27 00:00:00', 102))
            GROUP BY m1.MAILITM_FID
  ) oj ON m.MAILITM_FID = oj.Ref3033 
WHERE  (m.MAIL_CLASS_CD = 'E') 
   AND (me.EVENT_OFFICE_CD = 1063) 
   AND (me.EVENT_TYPE_CD = 30) 
   AND (me.EVENT_GMT_DT >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-27 00:00:00', 102)) 
   AND (me.EVENT_GMT_DT < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-05-28 00:00:00', 102))
```

I didn't check the logic of your joins, I just moved them. Try and see if there's still this syntax error..

Comment: Thanks for your responce, but there a syntax error                  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: Sql Server ENTREPRISE Edition version 9.00.4035.00

Comment: I changed some aliases now, the join didn't have one to refer to. Could you try it now?

Answer (score 3):

Move your `WHERE` syntax underneath your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` has to be part of the `FROM` statement.

Comment: didn't work, i have just two table and those are two separated query

Comment: @AymenRM: If it didn't work, then either you did something wrongly or you forgot to add some details about your query. Valamas's suggestion is correct: your LEFT OUTER JOIN part is misplaced, because joins are part of the FROM clause and the WHERE clause must go after FROM, i.e. after all the joins too.

Comment: hope this edit can help, the tables L_MAILITM_EVENTS_1 and L_MAILITM_1 are just image of L_MAILITM_EVENTS and L_MAILITM

Comment: please post your edited code, because this is still incorrect

Comment: excuse me, but how can i do this ?

Comment: click the edit button of your question and paste your actual query :-)

Comment: @Sebas i see all my question as i want ! see this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/10874740/777362